# Can a lower bound of $A$ be strictly greater than an upper bound of $A$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is the argument I've seen for the boundedness of the empty set:

> Fix a real number $M$.
>
> I claim that $M$ is an upper bound for the empty set $A$.
>
> I can phrase what I have to check as: if $a$ is an element of $A$ then $a$ is less than or equal to $M$.
>
> So we have to decide if a statement of the form "if $p$ then $q$" is true.
>
> If $p$ is false then this statement is true whether $q$ is true or false. (This is the case where we often say it's "vacuously true".) Once we observe that $p$ is false, we don't even have to consider $q$.
>
> And this is our case here: "$a$ is an element of $A$" is false, because there are no elements of $A$.

And the same argument gives a lower bound.

So what, if anything, is wrong with the following argument?

\begin{align}
&\text{Let }M_1=0, \; M_2=1. \tag{Prop. 1} \\
&\text{Then, by the argument above, the empty set is}\\
&\text{bounded above by }M_1\text{ and} \tag{Prop. 2.1}
\\&\text{bounded below by }M_2. \tag{Prop. 2.2}\\
&\text{Therefore, either }\\
&0>1,\text{ or }\tag{Prop. 3.1}\\
&\text{a lower bound is strictly greater than an upper bound.} \tag{Prop. 3.2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a lower bound of $A$ can be strictly bigger than an upper bound of $A$, but only when $A$ is empty.

Specifically, if $l>u$ where $l$ is a lower bound of $A$ and $u$ is an upper bound of $A$, and if $A$ has an element $a$, then we would have the contradiction $a\leq u<l\leq a$. So if $l>u$ then $A$ cannot have an element.

Conversely, if $A$ is empty, then every number is both an upper and a lower bound of $A$, and so $l>u$ is possible.